# cut command: how use the delimiter to be considered/included within the field position?

Tags: command-line, string, cut

I want extract the version release of some file .gz/.zip installers.

Therefore if is executed (shown in this way for simplicity purposes):

```
echo "apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz" | cut -d'-' -f 3
echo "gradle-7.3.1-bin.zip"          | cut -d'-' -f 2
```

They return `3.8.4` and `7.3.1` respectively. Until here all is fine and expected.

But consider the following file name:

- `OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14_9.tar.gz`

I need extract `11.0.14_9`, therefore so far with:

```
echo "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14_9.tar.gz" | cut -d'_' -f 5
```

It returns `11.0.14` and I need `11.0.14_9` (observer the `_9` part). How accomplish this goal?

Thinking in two possible scenarios: The file name could be either

```
OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14_9.tar.gz # with    '_number'
OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.tar.gz   # without '_number'
```

What could be the *unique* 'dynamic' command - ***if is possible*** - that let returns either `11.0.14_9` or `11.0.14`?

If other command can be used for this scenario, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -Eo "[0-9]+[0-9\.\_]{2,}" | tail -1 | sed 's/\.$//'` looks ugly but it works for your examples:

```
echo "apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+[0-9\.\_]{2,}" | tail -1 | sed 's/\.$//'
3.8.4
echo "gradle-7.3.1-bin.zip" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+[0-9\.\_]{2,}" | tail -1 | sed 's/\.$//'
7.3.1
echo "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14_9.tar.gz" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+[0-9\.\_]{2,}" | tail -1 | sed 's/\.$//'
11.0.14_9
```

`grep -Eo "[0-9]+[0-9\.\_]{2,}"` will match all strings beginning with at least one digit (**`[0-9]+`**), followed by two or more digits and/or `.` `_` characters (**`[0-9\.\_]{2,}`**). This will of course also match the `64_` from your 3rd example, so we only want the last match (**`tail -1`**). Finally this will include the trailing `.` so we strip that off with **`sed 's/\.$//'`**.

I'm certain there's a much neater and more compact way than what I've shown to accomplish this.